# Easily view a list of changes of upgraded packages

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-10.04, aptitude

So, let's say I run *sudo apt-get upgrade* on my Lucid Lynx and it upgrades a couple of packages I'm interested in. Is there a command to run that will open some kind of info or manual that tells me what changes were made in this new version of the package?

For instance, if I run the *apt-get upgrade* command and it installs a new version of empathy. Do I have to go over to their site to review the changes made in this version, or is there a quicker command line way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/apt-listchanges.1.html
apt-listchanges  —  Show  new  changelog  entries  from  Debian package archives.
OR(easier way in my opinion) >
 `aptitude changelog amarok`
`aptitude changelog amarok=2.1.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

#### apt-listchanges example

If necessary on first use, install the package (85 kB):

```sh
apt install apt-listchanges
```

Depending on your config ([details here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897513/apt-command-does-not-cache-the-deb-files)), the deb file for a package you've installed may be in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. If it's not, or for a package you haven't installed yet, download the deb (here for a package called foo):

```sh
cd /tmp
apt download foo
```

Now display both news and changelogs for the package:

```sh
apt-listchanges --which=both foo_version.deb
```